# How to listen opusCodec in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer, ogg

I am working on an watchOS app.

There is a .ogg opus file locally and I need to listen to it on AVplayer.
But AVPlayer currently does not support it.

To listen on AVPlayer, I need to decode the opus file as I understand. So I followed these two threads which are
[How to decode self-delimited opus in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597315/how-to-decode-self-delimited-opus-in-ios) and [How to encode and decode Real-time Audio using OpusCodec in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692517/how-to-encode-and-decode-real-time-audio-using-opuscodec-in-ios) but I couldn't succeed.

I always get error while decoding data.

I have been trying for 2 days to find a solution. Can anybody explain how I can do it?